# addUpdateContent modifies content body

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

Building a Gmail AddOn, I'm using next code to modify body content on compose view:

```
var response = CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder()
    .setUpdateDraftBodyAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftBodyAction()
        .addUpdateContent(HTML, CardService.ContentType.MUTABLE_HTML)
        .setUpdateType(CardService.UpdateDraftBodyType.IN_PLACE_INSERT))
    .build();
```

if HTML var contains `<img src="">` tag, with something like:

```
var HTML = "<img src='https://www.img.com?id=422905de&linkGuid=&url=&type=email&referrerUrl=' height='1' width='1'>"
```

once it is attached to compose view looks like this

```
<img src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/C2s_vqWMJJkSPDMkWknfh1oop1hokrhvIjiMoDP7-pTeSyPe38_EgAQSpjob9cV8i6kKT6NUyQVvOErKIsZx_Ey8kN0r9xfx1n842DrOlCgjO0PTT_oQuynCkB_M53iYdtdGtN3ArXi3p3elizleGa14lQNx6KAiJ8L7xPjX4kp8Dhe1zgdB2eCNEx5V20eZbBSm-3ETldi03ibEQM8b6XUUGHAq3jzSkeqWxyjQLDpTDIen7WbfKw3ti-vKZrql0=s0-d-e1-ft#https://www.img.com?id=422905de&linkGuid=&url=&type=email&referrerUrl=" height="1" width="1">
```

if I use CardService.ContentType.TEXT, I can see that URL is attached as expected (but in text)

```
<img src='https://www.img.com?id=422905de&linkGuid=&url=&type=email&referrerUrl=' height='1' width='1'>
```

So it seems, that using MUTABLE_HTML or IMMUTABLE_HTML in contentType modifies URL once it is executed.

Is there anyway to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: This appears to be working as intended. Did you find a workaround.?

Comment: No, seems that images from a url if they are embed/added from a browser they get cached "by default" on insertion, although if they are added from gmail mobile app, they are cached when they are sent and received.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the client-side to add the src attribute?

### Example:

```js
var HTML = "<img id='image-id'><script>document.getElementById('image-id').setAttribute('src','https://www.img.com?id=422905de&linkGuid=&url=&type=email&referrerUrl=')</script>"
```

### Update:

The second example [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui#example_2) shows how to insert an image in the draft composer. I believe the only difference is that they are using a "/>" closing slash and bracket for the  tag.

### Update 2:

This is working as intended, as images and other content get sanitized by Google as pointed out by @Pataquer in the comments. And one thing to note is that the mutability of the HTML is about whether the inserted HTML content is meant to be editable by the user running the add-on.

Comment: I doesn't work either. Looks like they also clean any js execution. result for this line on compose view is <img>

Comment: Also for MUTABLE_HTML?

Comment: yes, MUTABLE/IMMUTABLE_HTML you get result that I showed you. If you do text, it is not processed but either show an image.